# Is it possible to user flutter_markdown custom builder with expandable widget?

Tags: flutter, markdown, expandable

I want to represent markdown string as expandable widgets with title and collapse content. I use the [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) plugin to create widgets with collapsed content and the [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) plugin to render content under the title in collapsed area. But I need to parse the markdown myself into my own model classes.

I found out that the `MarkdownBody` widget has an `builders` field, in which we can specify our own widget that should be used for render specific markdown tag. As I understand it, it is intended for custom rendering of any tags (classic, your own tags or tags from extensions).

Can I use a custom `MarkdownElementBuilder` to create multiple tags display in one widget (`h2` and following `p` im my case)? How can I achieve the result as shown in the screenshot using the custom `MarkdownElementBuilder`?

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: @Nux Unfortunately, no.